# From where should I install git: xcode-select --install or brew install git?

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

From where should I install git:
`xcode-select --install` or `brew install git`?

Comment: Don't you need to `xcode-select --install` either way? You need it installed to use brew anyhow. The only question then is whether you want a bleeding-edge new git installation (if so then use brew too).

Comment: i already installed git using xcode-select, will there be two git versions running if i do brew install git now or will it upgrade the old git?

Comment: Please use the [tag:homebrew] tag instead of [tag:BREW].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do `xcode-select --install` anyway if you want to do any development.

You can then do

```
brew install git
```

and it will install `git` into `/usr/local/bin/git` without affecting the Apple Xcode `git`. There will not be two git versions *running*, but there will be two *installed*. Which one runs when you type `git` will depend on your PATH. In general, you would want `/usr/local/bin` first on your PATH so you benefit from the newer packages provided by **homebrew** rather than the outdated versions Apple supplies.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise downloading with homebrew. You'll benefit from the frequent updates which will give you access to newer features and more stability.

It's nice that Apple decided to give users an easy way to download programming tools, but they are very out dated.