# Cant find git path in VSCode OSX

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio

So I've had quite some trouble trying to get git and VS Code to work together, I've found the $PATH for git in terminal (/usr/bin/git) but when I try to edit it in settings.json this doesn't seem to work. Null stays. Do you have any other method to get this working? I've even tried exporting the $PATH in terminal.

Comment: I've written it like this in settings.json - `git.path: /usr/bin/git`

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm on lates VSCode and have the same problem. Cannot find where to put the path though.

Comment: @Ola I did manage to get it to work after some workarounds. Ill write more about it later.

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by 2 issues:

1. In VS Code -> Preferences -> Settings, make sure you put this line:

   "git.path": "/usr/bin"

It was set to null in my installation. Also, in the latest version of Code, the user settings are opened in a side window and you add your value there.

2. If you have Xcode installed, make sure you open it and accept the license agreement. Git was refusing to start in my installation until I accepted the Xcode license.

Comment: @Dave: VSCode won’t do that. However, you only have to do it once.

Comment: After this configuration, I had no visual representation that any change has taken effect. VSCode only really seemed to recognize git for me after I opened a git repository

Comment: Quick update on this - not sure if it was specific to my setup or if it's a new VS Code requirement but I had to make my `git.path` equal to `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: Same for me: "If you have Xcode installed, make sure you open it and accept the license agreement. Git was refusing to start in my installation until I accepted the Xcode license." ... Just opened XCode and agreed the licence. Thanks

Comment: for me this only worked after restarting vscode

Comment: Simple run in terminal "which git" then in settings.json put line like:   "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git" in my case.  Was problem with Ventura macOS (darwin22) and VsCode

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that Xcode had updated it's legal Terms and I hadn't agreed to them yet so it was blocking VScode from using git. I found this out by running the command

```
git status
```

And I got back:

```
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.
```

So I followed the instructions and agreed to the Xcode/iOS license. Then I restarted VScode and my gitlens extension worked like a charm!

Comment: You just pulled me back from the brink of madness. I've been banging my head against the wall with this for hours and this was fix. Thank you so much,

Comment: I was running `git status` without any complaint of the license, however I still had the VSCode error. After seeing this I ran `sudo xcodebuild -license` anyway and it turned out I hadn't agreed to it, despite not receiving a warning. After that VSCode worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can test and check your vscode without any extension and maybe it will work!
It works for me, test it this way :

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then write: `reload window with extensions disabled`

now check if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers suggest, you can do XCode license agreement.

When I did that I was a bit unhappy about downloading 11 GB of Xcode just for license agreement.
I've got the hint to install `git` as well as `Node` via `brew` which then will manage the dependencies, because also Node is sometimes managed by Xcode license

So next time you have a new fresh OS use in your shell:

```
brew install git
```

Some more information about the two [gits on the operating system here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989618/from-where-should-i-install-git-xcode-select-install-or-brew-install-git).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all answers. Here is what I think is my problem.

For this install I must mount a folder via SSH (there are many many test servers connected that I cannot set up locally) and on the server it finds git 1.8.3. So I just ignores it for now.