# How to make sure to agree to GIT license agreement in VS CODE source control module (SCM) on Mac OS mojave?

Tags: git, visual-studio, macos-mojave

After updating Mac os to Mojave, vs code does not anymore detect git as default source control. I added "git.path": "/usr/bin" in user settings. Others on stack overflow suggest to accept git license cond. but it does not pop up upon launching vscode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant find git path in VSCode OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610666/cant-find-git-path-in-vscode-osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have Git installed on your computer Git will refuse to start in my installation until you accept the Xcode license. In my case ...when I used a git command in the terminal it will ask you to accept the agreement, otherwise, if you have Xcode installed, make sure you open it and accept the license agreement.

Comment: running git via terminal generated error "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun" But xcode-select --install did the job.